# What are different ways to provide a semantics to a language?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, functional-programming

Suppose you have 1. a grammar for terms of a language; 2. type-assignment rules, 3. a set of reduction rules. You want to prove that your language is adequate for mathematical reasoning. If I understand correctly, the right way to do it is to develop a semantics for it, and then prove certain desirable properties such as soundness and consistency.

I've seen different approaches to this. Usually, a model in set theory is involved. But I believe that is not the only way to do it. Wouldn't, for example, an interpreter for that language on the untyped λ-calculus count as a semantics? So, my question is: what are the different ways to provide a semantics to language?

Comment: A reference request like yours is too broad for Stack Exchange -- you ask for a survey of a whole research area! You need to narrow your focus considerably before a question of reasonable scope appears. Try talking to your advisor(s), search with [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=some+query) and check out [this guide to better (re)searches](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13594/1419) on [academia.SE].

Comment: @Raphael I don't see how this question calls for a survey. chi's answer seems pretty satisfactory to me. If I had an objection to this question, it would be that it's pretty much calling for the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)), but I don't think that particular article presents the information very well.

Comment: @Gilles A short survey is still a survey, and better replaced by a textbook. But if you think otherwise, fair enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many possible approaches. Here's a few "classic" styles.

- Operational semantics (e.g. small step / reduction, or big step)
- Denotational semantics (e.g. domain-theoretic, or category-theoretic)
- Axiomatic semantics (e.g. hoare logic)

You can also define the semantics of a language through a translation to another language (already having its semantics). CPS transforms could also be mentioned here.

Also note that many languages admit several distinct semantics. Lazy & eager semantics of functional programs are possible, for instance. Prolog also has many different semantics (I recall someone stating "there's no such a thing as THE semantics of Prolog").

Further, concurrent languages like CCS or $\pi$-calculus have a LTS semantics. Game semantics is also used sometimes (but I don't know much about it).

I'm pretty sure there are many other kinds of semantics. I'd be surprised if in the future someone does not invent a new kind of semantics.